# Image sequence animation on scroll when element is reached

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll

I'm trying to implement an animation that switches images on scroll when it's wrapping div scrolls into the viewport. My problem is that the animation starts as soon as someone starts scrolling, so the animation is already at the end when #wrapper comes into viewport.

How to achieve that the animation starts when #wrapper scrolls into the viewport?

Unfortunately my JS/jQuery knowledge is very poor but this is what I got til now:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jowie/x4vpz153/1/)

HTML:

```
<div class="page_content_before_image_animation">
  <p>lorem ipsum …</p>
    </div>
      <div id="load" data-images="19"></div>
        <div id="wrapper">
          <img class="sequenzbilder" src="https://twdp.de/sequence/1.jpg" width="600" height="661" />
        </div>
```

JS:

```
var images = [];
    for (i = 1; i <= $('#load').attr('data-images'); i++) {
      images.push('https://twdp.de/sequence/' + i + '.jpg');
    }
    
    $(images).each(function() {
      $('<img class="sequenzbilder" />')[0].src = this;
    });
    
    
    var totalImages = images.length;
    
    var pageHeight = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
    var scrollInterval = Math.floor(pageHeight / 140);
    
    var viewport = $(window),
      slowdown;
    viewport.on('scroll', function() {
      i = Math.floor($(this).scrollTop() / scrollInterval);
      $('.sequenzbilder').attr('src', images[i]);
      slowdown = Math.ceil(viewport.scrollTop() / 20);
    });
```

Comment: Made some quick adaptations, seems to work alright. Sequence starts when the image reaches the bottom of the screen and ends when the bottom of the image passes it: https://jsfiddle.net/guswcrt9

Comment: This works pretty perfect. Thanks a lot! Since I don't understand what you've done exactly I moved the image itself a little bit more up via CSS. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad to help, should work in all cases regardless of the exact position and size of the image. And it will recalculate on resize so it's responsive as well.